# Move select rows to another column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame with columns for start_time, end_time, and time_of_capture. I have noticed there is a select set of rows that have been mis-inputted into the end_time that should be the start_time since the time_of_capture is greater than the end_time.

| start_time | end_time | time_of_capture |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :00 | 00:30:00 | 00:37:00 |
| :00 | 01:30:00 | 01:37:00 |
| :00 | 01:40:00 | 01:45:00 |
| 00:20:00 | 1:35:00 | 00:21:00 |

So I need to to move values from the end_time column into the start_time column when the time_of_capture is greater then the end_time. I have tried a variety of case_whens but could not get values to input. The expected output for this example is to move those first 3 end_time values to the start_time column as there can not be a time_of_capture occurring after the end_time.

data

```
structure(list(start_time = c("22:00:00", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "18:30:00", "NA", "NA", "NA", "18:30:00", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "17:00:00", "18:30:00", "18:30:00", 
"19:50:00", "NA"), end_time = c("23:15:00", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "19:45:00", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"19:45:00", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "18:15:00", "19:45:00", 
"19:45:00", "21:16:00", "NA"), time_of_capture = c("22:19:00", 
"22:19:00", "22:19:00", "22:23:00", "22:27:00", "22:29:00", "22:30:00", 
"22:33:00", "23:38:00", "23:45:00", "19:08:00", "19:40:00", "19:17:00", 
"17:52:00", "18:35:00", "00:07:00", "00:08:00", "00:10:00", "00:15:00", 
"00:23:00", "17:22:00", "18:39:00", "18:32:00", "19:52:00", "19:59:00"
)), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is your expected ouput here?

Comment: @Maël updated for expected outcome

Comment: Could you please share your sample data with `dput()`? That way we will get all the class information in a copy/pasteable format, which will let us know how much converting we need to do to make a solution work and also help guarantee that a solution will work on your actual data. `dput(your_data[1:4, c("start_time", "end_time", "time_of_capture")])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 4 rows of those columns.

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you for the input about dput. I have now included the example. The sample above does not capture the example I have provided above.

Comment: I mean, please do choose a sample to share that illustrates the problem. If the first 4 rows are not a good choice, pick other rows. I just used `1:4` since there were 4 rows in what you showed originally.

Comment: Also, your `dput()` doesn't have an `end_time` column, so there are no values to move.

Comment: Essentially you want `pmin` and `pmax`, something like `your_data %>% mutate(mint = pmin(start_time, end_time), end_time = pmax(start_time, end_time), start_time = mint, mint = NULL)`. Without data to test on not sure if that will work as-is or if it will take a little massaging.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for helping me update the data. I believe a sample should be correct. the pmin is along the right tracks and I am working with it now. thank you